# Showing Sidebar Background in Login in Angular

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, user-interface, angular-http

I have a problem in my app. The sidebar menus doesn't show up in my login BUT the sidebar background is still showing up. If i put the router-outlet outside of the 
(div class="page home-page") the homepage is broken? How can i remove the sidebar background without destroying the homepage?

> app.component.html

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="authService.isLoggedIn()">
    <app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
</ng-template>

<div class="page home-page"> 
    <ng-template [ngIf]="authService.isLoggedIn()">   
      <app-header></app-header>
    </ng-template>

        <router-outlet></router-outlet>


    <ng-template [ngIf]="authService.isLoggedIn()">  
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import{ NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { SettingsComponent } from './settings/settings.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth/auth-guard.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/settings', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'settings', component: SettingsComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules})
    ],

    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {

}
```

Comment: Where did you put the sidebar back ground , it depends on the any css class ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi. I mean I have to separate the  (div class="page home-page") and the login component. The  (div class="page home-page")  should not contain the login component.